# TypeError for leetcode Python coding question

Tags: python

Hi guys I ma practicing a Python coding question on leetcode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/description/

Here is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self,nums):
          result = []
          result.append(nums[0])
          for n in range(len(nums)):
            result_ref = False
            for x in range(n):
              if nums[x] == nums[n]:
                result_ref = False
              else:
                result_ref = True
            if result_ref:
              result.append(nums[n])
            else:
              continue

          return result
```

The function works fine in my computer, but I kept get this error in my leetcode console. Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you very much!

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
Line 25 in integerListToString (Solution.py)
Line 42 in main (Solution.py)
Line 48 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: What's the line where the error is reported?

Comment: The error does not seem to correspond to your code.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at default code @ https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/description/

```
class Solution(object):

    def removeDuplicates(self, nums): 

        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
```

rtype should be int, but you return boolean

as soon as you will change 'result' to int - this will disappear:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

btw afaik Python 2 is too old - imo Python 3.x is much more interesting to learn ;)